# ¿Como contar registros por fecha segun la consulta solicitada?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Busco realizar el conteo de estos servicios segun la fecha, estos tipos de servicios quedan almacenados en una columna.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "es">
    <head>
        <title>Consulta De Estadisticas</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/bootstrap.css"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8" name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    </head>
<body>
    <nav class = "navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class = "container-fluid">
            <a href = "" class = "navbar-brand">Estadisticas Aerosanidad</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class = "row-fluid">
        <div class = "col-md-3"></div>
        <div class = "col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h3 class = "text-primary">Búsqueda De Servicios</h3>
                <hr style = "border-top:1px dotted #000;"/>
                <div class = "form-inline">
                <label>Desde:</label>
                <input type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Inicio"  id = "date1"/>
                <label>Hasta</label>
                <input type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Final"  id = "date2"/>
                <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary" id = "btn_search" onclick="load();"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button> <button type = "button" id = "reset" class = "btn btn-success"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"><span></button>
            </div>
            <br /><br />
            <div class = "table-responsive">    
                <table class = "table table-bordered alert-warning">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style = "width:25%;">Servicios Solicitados</th>
                            <th style = "width:30%;">Servicios Finalizados</th>
                            <th>Servicios Fallidos</th>
                            <th style = "width:20%;">Servicios Cancelados</th>
                            <th style = "width:20%;">Servicios Realizando</th>
                        </tr>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id = "load_data">

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>  

              </div>
        </div>
            <input type="submit" name="volver" value="Herramienta" class="submit" onclick="location='http://localhost/Aeroasistencia/Estadisticas/index.php'">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src = "js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src = "js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src = "js/ajax.js"></script>
</html>

    ajax_data.php
    <?php
$date1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date1']));
$date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date2']));

if (!empty($_POST['date1']) and  !empty($_POST['date1'])){
    list($dia,$mes,$anio)=explode("/",$_POST['date1']);
    $date1="$anio-$mes-$dia";
    list($dia,$mes,$anio)=explode("/",$_POST['date2']);
    $date2="$anio-$mes-$dia";

    $sWhere="WHERE `fecha_Solicitud` BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'";

} else {
    $sWhere=""; 
}

#Conectare a la base de datos

include("conexion.php");

$q_book = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(servicio_No) AS totalServicios FROM `servicio` $sWhere") or die(mysqli_error("Error al conectar a la base de datos"));
$v_book = $q_book->num_rows;
$totalServicios = $v_book['totalServicios']; //Este es el valor que acabas de calcular en la consulta
if($v_book > 0){
    while($f_book = $q_book->fetch_array()){
    ?>
    <tr>
         <td><?php echo $f_book['totalServicios']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta con que utilices `GROUP By` en tu consulta MySQL

```
    <?php
$date1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date1']));
$date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['date2']));

if (!empty($_POST['date1']) and  !empty($_POST['date2'])){
    list($dia,$mes,$anio)=explode("/",$_POST['date1']);
    $date1="$anio-$mes-$dia";
    list($dia,$mes,$anio)=explode("/",$_POST['date2']);
    $date2="$anio-$mes-$dia";

    $sWhere="WHERE `fecha_Solicitud` BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'";

} else {
    $sWhere=""; 
}
```

#Conectare a la base de datos

```
include("conexion.php");

// agregas GROUP BY indicando la columna por la cual agrupar
$q_book = $conn->query("SELECT `fecha_Solicitud`, COUNT(servicio_No) AS totalServicios FROM `servicio` $sWhere GROUP BY `fecha_Solicitud`") or die(mysqli_error("Error al conectar a la base de datos"));
$v_book = $q_book->num_rows;
if($v_book > 0){
    while($f_book = $q_book->fetch_array()){
    ?>
    <tr>
         <td><?php echo $f_book['totalServicios']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
  }
```

para obtener la fecha relacionada a cada conteo de servicios usas `$f_book['fecha_Solicitud']`

Comment: Lo que necesito es realizar el conteo de los registros segun el servicio, en este caso si me esta contando la cantidad de servicios solicitados porque me estan contando cada registro pero necesito contar cuantos fueron Finalizados, Fallidos y cancelados estos tres tipos de servicio se guardan en una columna llamada estado si me entiendes?

Comment: lo mismo, solo agregas la columna `estado` al GROUP BY y al SELECT, el COUNT no es necesario, obtienes el conteo por otros medios: "SELECT `fecha_Solicitud`, `estado`, `servicio_No` FROM servicio $sWhere GROUP BY `servicio`,`fecha_Solicitud`,`estado`"Aquí lo importante es como ordenas tus columnas en GROUP BY y que es lo que necesitas contar exactamente para definir tu consulta

Comment: estamos cerca del objetivo

Comment: en esa columna estado se puede se pueden guardar Finalizado, Fallido, Realizando

Comment: cuando utilizas GROUP BY en una columna lo que hace MySQL es que divide los resultados por cada valor diferente de cada columna para agrupar, así si tienes GROUP BY fecha_Solicitud,estado lo que hará es que primero te agrupará los resultados por cada fecha diferente y dentro te agrupará cada resultado por estado, algo como: 2018-07-06 => [Fallido => 12, Completado => 68] dependiendo de los diferentes estados y fechas que haya registrados, no se si me explico, por eso te decía que tu consulta depende como quieres organizar tu resultado

Comment: la desventaja es que solo puedes traer un numero reducido de campos, en este caso lo que buscas es el número total de registros por cada estado y por cada fecha por lo que solo deberías hacer COUNT(*) o COUNT(id) sobre tu consulta con el GROUP BY sobre fecha_Solicitud y estado, algo como: SELECT fecha_Solicitud, estado, COUNT(id) AS numero_registros FROM servicios $where GROUP BY fecha_Solicitud,estado, esto te devolverá algo como lo que puse en el comentario anterior